Can you use お～する for third person requests?
From Kakegurui chapter 3, I encountered this phrase 誰か外へお連れして, which is supposed to mean "somebody please take [her] to outside" based on context.

I wonder why お～する form is used here? I thought this construction is restricted to actions done by speakers. Is it wrong? I expected something like 誰か外へお連れになって.
Perhaps, she is using this construction on purpose? お～する is a humble speech pattern reserved for speakers to lower their own status to listeners. In the manga, it seems like she viewed her as a low-class scum after she lost the game and accumulated debt. Her use of お～する indicates that she didn't respect her as a person of equal status?

Whose action do you think 連れる (or 連れて行く) is?

This is a perfectly valid and natural use of keigo, and there is nothing rude or offensive in the sentence. In this scene, the speaker must show respect to the guest (Saotome), not to someone referred to as "誰か". This "somebody" refers to a person who belongs to the same organization as the speaker, and they must show the same level of respect to Saotome as the speaker herself does. That's why humble language is appropriate here.
In general, you must use humble language not only for your own actions but also for actions done by members of your in-group (such as colleagues or family members) when showing respect to someone outside your group. For details, please read: 係りの山田は、すぐに参ります。‐Yamada, the person in charge, is coming soon‐

It appears to me that the answer is obvious. You can use 謙遜語 for yourself or anyone close to you.

Why downvote? Is it wrong?

The answer seems insufficient because it does not explain the important condition regarding when it is appropriate to use 謙譲語 to the listener.

On top of what naruto said: Because saying "the answer is obvious" to someone asking something is usually not a very productive state of affairs.

Well, it's my own question. I wouldn't use that phrase when answering others obviously.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
